# How to select an object inside array that has a specific value in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How do I select an object inside an array where the object has the the value "A" for the "slug" key?

for example if I have this:

```
 var allItems = [
    {
        "slug": "henk",
        "company_founded": "2008",
        "company_category": "Clean",
        "company_logo": false,
        "company_description": "",
    }
    {
        "id": "bas",
        "company_founded": "2012",
        "company_category": "Health",
        "company_logo": false,
        "company_description": "",
    }
    {
        "slug": "jan",
        "company_founded": "2005",
        "company_category": "Clean",
        "company_logo": false,
        "company_description": "",
    }
]
```

What I want is to put the object that contains the slug : henk inside a new variable.

So I will have something like this to work with:

```
var = SelectedItem = {
    "slug": "henk",
    "company_founded": "2012",
    "company_category": "Health",
    "company_logo": false,
    "company_description": "",
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Iterate and compare? Not really sure what the issue is.

Comment: if you want the `henk` subobject, why are you saying you need to get the `bas` one out of it?

Comment: please state, what you are looking for, what value what key have and why the result is with henk and 2012?

Comment: IF you had a consistent set of elements you could create a lookup but there is no consistency so you have to iterate the list for the specific instance.

Comment: I was looking for  a way to select the object that contains henk. But it's solved thanks!

Comment: @Mark Schulthesis What do you mean by consistent set of elements?

Comment: Well for instance if they all had a "slug" property you could use that as a lookup - for the value of "slug" matching some lookup value, henk in this case.  But some objects have no "slug" thus my "inconsistent" comment.  I can post an example with this assumption if you like.

Comment: Ah oke I see thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to iterate your list and based on your condition take the element that you are looking for:

```
var result;
for each (var item in allItems ) {
    if(item.company_founded === "2012") {
        result = item; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg so obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @RaymondtheDeveloper You are welcome. However, if you have a lot of data and need to look up items very often from such a list/set then you might want to consider converting your list into a dictionary. This would allow you to access an item much faster through one particular identifier. This is what Fire Crow suggested. Of course you don't need that if you have to do that only once, or let's say, not that often that it would have bad impact on actual performance.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider storing the values in an object indexed by the expected keys, such as:

```
var allItems = {
  "henk":
    {
        "slug": henk,
        "company_founded": "2008",
        "company_category": "Clean",
        "company_logo": false,
        "company_description": "",
    },
  "bas":
    {
        "id": bas,
        "company_founded": "2012",
        "company_category": "Health",
        "company_logo": false,
        "company_description": "",
    }
]
```

this allows you to retrieve a value like `allItems.henk`

it indexes faster because it's a logarithmic hash-table look up instead of a full iteration.

----- edit ----

if you need to transform it in advance to accelerate lookup, as long as the cost of generating the new structure is less than the cost of the lookups you will be doing. you can do,

```
var allItemsByKey = {}
for(var i = 0, l = allItems.length; i<l; i++){
   var item = allItems[i];
   allItemsByKey[item.slug] = item;
}
```

then `allItemsByKey` has the structure demonstrated above

Comment: Ah yes this is indeed the best way to store values. But it's generated by an external party where I have no control of. I'll use this way for my own when I need to. Thanks!

Comment: a transformation may not be inefficient depending on the problem space, I'll amend the response

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look up into [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
 var obj = allItems.find(function(el){
     return el.slug === 'henk';
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

For mixed up object, you can iterate over all properties and return only the object which some propertiy has a certain value.

```js
var allItems = [{ "slug": "henk", "company_founded": "2008", "company_category": "Clean", "company_logo": false, "company_description": "", }, { "id": "bas", "company_founded": "2012", "company_category": "Health", "company_logo": false, "company_description": "", }, { "slug": "jan", "company_founded": "2005", "company_category": "Clean", "company_logo": false, "company_description": "", }],
    result = allItems.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(a).some(function (k) {
            return a[k] === 'henk';
        });
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it consistent: Array of objects (put comma between, changed id to slug to match others.)

Assumption is that the property is unique OR it will get the LAST ONE in the list.  Like an ID lookup or some such.

**EDITED** to show value within complex object vs simple array
**EDIT2**: add second lookup by category

```
var allItems = {"fred":"H fred",rats:"rats",lookupitems: [{
  "slug": "henk",
  "company_founded": "2008",
  "company_category": "Clean",
  "company_logo": false,
  "company_description": "",
} ,{
  "slug": "bas",
  "company_founded": "2012",
  "company_category": "Health",
  "company_logo": false,
  "company_description": "",
}, {
  "slug": "jan",
  "company_founded": "2005",
  "company_category": "Clean",
  "company_logo": false,
  "company_description": "",
}]};
```

Create a lookup we can use in a repeatable fashion:

```
var lookup = {};
var lookupbycategory = {};
// create reference to list above and use it everywhere
lookup.list = allItems.lookupitems;
for (var i = 0, len = lookup.list.length; i < len; i++) {
  lookup[lookup.list[i].slug] = lookup.list[i];
  lookupbycategory[lookup.list[i].company_category] = lookup.list[i];
}
```

Get one (use it)

```
var mychoice = lookup["henk"];
alert(JSON.stringify(mychoice));
alert(JSON.stringify(lookupbycategory["Clean"]));
```

reuse it

```
var mybas = lookup["bas"];
```